# Formula Help Needed: Calculating Dates to Exclude Weekends

Tags: list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time, formula

I am trying to set up several dates on a list in SharePoint. The dates all relate to each other, and I want to exclude weekends when calculating these dates.

I have three date columns: “Request Date” -> “Draft Due” -> “Final Due”

**Formulas Needed:**

1. The “Draft Due” date needs to be 8 days after the “Request Date” (this is excluding weekends).
2. The “Final Due” date needs to be 2 days after the “Draft Due” date (again, this is also excluding weekends).

Can someone please help me write these two formulas?